# Showing data from state variable in ReactJS forms infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, setstate

I'm trying to show data from an API call. The structure of the application looks like

`MainComponent` -> `RefreshButton` (this will fetch the data)

`MainComponent` -> `ShowData` (this will show the data that is being fetched)

`MainComponent` has a state `userData` that will store the response that was received from the API. Now the issue is, whenever I'm clicking the button, it is getting into an infinite loop of rendering and calls the API infinite times.

**This is what the error shows:**

[image]

**Here is my `MainComponent` -**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import RefreshButton from "./RefreshButton";
import ShowData from "./ShowData";

const MainComponent = () => {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(userData);
    }, [userData]);

    return (
        <div>
            <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Main Component</p>

            <RefreshButton setUserData={setUserData} />
            {userData && <ShowData userData={userData} />}
        </div>
    );
};

export default MainComponent;
```

**Here is my `RefreshButton` component -**

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const RefreshButton = ({ setUserData }) => {
    const getData = () => {
        axios
            .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos`)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.status === 200) setUserData(response.data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    };

    return (
        <div className="button-container">
            <button className="fetch-data-button" onClick={() => getData()}>
                Fetch new data
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default RefreshButton;
```

**And here is my `ShowData` component -**

```
import React from "react";

const ShowData = ({ userData }) => {
    console.log("Here", userData);
    return (
        <>
            {userData.map((info, idx) => (
                <div className="user-data" key={idx}>
                    {info}
                </div>
            ))}
        </>
    );
};

export default ShowData;
```

**PS** - I'm new to React and couldn't find a potential solution on this, there are several tutorials on how to fetch data from API calls and show it, but I wanted to know what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't seem to do anything wrong here. It makes infite loop of calling the same request you mean?

Comment: I checked the API you are using. It returns an array of objects. Those objects cannot be displayed directly using `{info}` in `ShowData`. You should use `{info.title}`, {info.id}`, etc. Other than that your code seems fine and does not seem to cause an infinite loop.

Comment: You really should paste the error that youre getting.

Comment: @Kostas yes! It was a render error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **You might have misunderstood with the infinite loop error**

**It's actually a render error as being shown here:**

[image]

**To fix your render error, simply put an actual string variable in the `{}`**

Because the response was an array of this object, so you can't simply render the whole object but need to pick an actual string variable inside:

```
[{
   "userId": 1,
   "id": 1,
   "title": "delectus aut autem",
   "completed": false
}],
```

**Change to something like this:**

```
const ShowData = ({ userData }) => {
  console.log("Here", userData);
  return (
    <>
      {userData.map((info, idx) => (
        <div className="user-data" key={idx}>
          {info.title}  // <-- Put a title here.
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Cheers! Just need to pay a bit more focus on the `error messages`, they are super helpful

Comment: Sure! I'll pay more attention to the error messages :)

Answer (score -2):

Remove

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(userData);
},[userData])
```

This will reevaluate component whenever user data changes, which Leeds to call showData infinitely

Comment: In this case, a console log will only be written when there is change in userdata, and it will not call showData infinitely

Comment: `useEffect` is literally an "Effect" after any state/prop change but not causing any re-render